# Set maximum date in date picker in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, date, datepicker

I have two date pickers, datePicker1 and datePicker2.
When user select a date in datePicker1, maximum date in datePicker2 sholud be the date after six months from date selected datePicker1.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please explain what you have already tried and what problems you are facing to make your question more focused. As it stands, your question is akin to "I want to do this thing, please give me code on how to do it..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `ValueChanged` of the first date picker and then set the max value of the second date picker.

```cs
datePicker1.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
    datePicker2.MaximumDateTime = datePicker1.Value.AddMonths(6);

    // Make sure that the existing set value of the 2nd Date Picker is less than the max
   if (datePicker2.Value > datePicker2.MaximumDateTime)
      datePicker2.Value = datePicker2.MaximumDateTime;
}
```

Place that code in your Load method.